# How to force sqlalchemy to treat a column as a string?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to extract data from MSSQL Server 2005. I have a table that contains a column containing values such as `0x0000000000881C3C, 0x0000000000881C3D, 0x0000000000881C3E, 0x0000000000881C3F`.

The column type is timestamp. I used reflection to check the column type and the column type is determined correctly by sqlalchemy. However when I use a query to extract the data, the data type returned is a bytearray.

For a source row that has the following values:

```
0x0000000000881C3C,35,1880744, AR,2014-05-13 13:04:53.000, N, 106,  1B3448E8-4D2F-46A0-87B9-ED07411F1478, NULL, NULL
```

the values returned by sqlalchemy are as follows:

```
(bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x1c<'), 35, 1880744, 'AR', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 13, 13, 4, 53), 'N', 106, '1B3448E8-4D2F-46A0-87B9-ED07411F1478', None, None)
```

How can I prevent `0x0000000000881C3C` from being interpreted as a byte array? Is there a way that I can force sqlalchemy to treat that column as a string?

When I try to insert the above value into MongoDB, I run into issues. I tried using various combinations of decode and encode but nothing seems to work. I am at my wits end and would appreciate any help in this regard.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://my_uid:my_pwd@my_db')
metadata = MetaData()
conn = engine.connect()
opp_table = Table('MYTABLE', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
s = select([opp_table])
result = conn.execute(s)
for row in result.fetchall():
    print row
```

Comment: The same way you o in raw SQL, cast it to varchar: `sqlalchemy.sql.func.cast(db.table.column, 'VARCHAR')`

Comment: @PauloScardine: Thank you for the suggestion. I've edited my post to show the code that I am using. Could you let me know where or how exactly I should cast the column?

Comment: Can you provide the "CREATE TABLE" statement as well?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I can force sqlalchemy to treat that column as a
>   string?

Use `autoload` and `Columns` combined to [override reflected columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/reflection.html#overriding-reflected-columns):

```
...
from sqlalchemy.types import Unicode

opp_table = Table('MYTABLE', metadata, 
                  Column('your_column_name', Unicode(30)), 
                  autoload=True, 
                  autoload_with=engine)
```